# Uninitialized arrays in OCaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml

How can I define an uninitialized array in OCaml?

I try to do this way:

```
let arr = Array.make_matrix 2 2

Error: The type of this expression, '_a -> '_a array array,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

Of course I can fill matrix by 0. But then I have a problems with type, because I want to store in this array input and output channels (ic and oc) of two different users:

```
let fd, _ = conn in
let ic = Lwt_io.of_fd Lwt_io.Input fd in
let oc = Lwt_io.of_fd Lwt_io.Output fd in
```

Please, tell me, how can I fill such array?

Try to use answers.

```
let ic1 = ref None
...
ic1 := ic;

Error: This expression has type Lwt_io.input Lwt_io.channel
       but an expression was expected of type 'a option
```

---

```
let arr = Array.make_matrix 2 2 None
...
arr.(0).(0) <- ic;

Error: This expression has type Lwt_io.input Lwt_io.channel
       but an expression was expected of type 'a option
```

Comment: If it's an array of channels, then when you access an element you must get a channel. What channel would you get when you access an element of such an uninitialized array?

Comment: I have already written a right way to use option types.  Your code is not the same.

Answer (score 5):

In OCaml, you cannot build an array with its elements uninitialized.  You must initialize them with some default value of the same type you are going to fill later.

I am not familiar with `Lwt_io` and not sure there is a channel value you can use as a default. Generally, if it is hard to build such a default for some type `t`, you can use `t option` instead of `t` for the type of array elements and fill with `None`, with the cost of runtime check of `Some` and `None`.

If you can use a dummy channel value then,

```
let arr = Array.make_matrix 2 2 dummy_channel
arr.[0].[0] <- ch
```

but I am do not know you can use such a dummy value `Lwt_io`. otherwise,

```
let arr = Array.make_matrix 2 2 None
arr.[0].[0] <- Some ch
```

BTW, input channels and output channels have different types therefore you cannot push them into one array.  Probably what you should use here is several references of `'mode channel ref`, instead of one array.

```
let ichan = ref None
ichan := Some ich
let ochan = ref None
ochan := Some och
```

It is not very clear why the questioner wants mutability here.  Probably the right answer is not to use them at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer/ Understand your idea in order, but my OCaml knowledge is not deep.  How can I fill refs or arrays which will contain channels? Some example, if you do not complicate.

Comment: I extended my answer, but probably you should think you really need arrays or mutability...

Comment: Described attepmts of using your variants in question. You write that is  not right to use mutabilities or arrays here. So, what can I use instead of this? I need to switch between two users connected by telnet to the PVP game tic tac toe.

Comment: Your attempt is not as same as the one I wrote here. Please check.

Comment: For two player games like tictactoe, you do not need to use arrays or refs.  Thinks a recursive function which takes two sets of ic and oc which flips the sets for each turn:  `let chs1 = (ic1, oc1) and chs2 = (ic2, oc2) in let rec turn chsa chsb = ... turn chsb chsa in turn chs1 chs2`